# React Native adding splash screen in cold start of Android App

Tags: android, react-native, splash-screen, react-navigation

I am trying to add splash screen to my react native android app but its giving me weird behaviour whenever I get a (remote/local) notification and on click to the notification component mounting the screen again that already mounted by showing splash again. I added splash by following [this article](https://medium.com/handlebar-labs/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-to-a-react-native-app-ios-and-android-30a3cec835ae) of Spencer Carli.

I don't know this behaviour is because of the react native single activity android app or may be I am adding the splash activity above the main activity. I am using [this react-native-splash-screen package](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen) .

I have also created a [git repo for the Splash test](https://github.com/Shhzdmrz/SplashTest) for the above approach. Please Have a look on it.

I also tried splash without adding another activity using [this rn-splash-screen package](https://github.com/mehcode/rn-splash-screen) but that will give me white screen before splash or you can say on the cold start.

As I am not a native android developer but I want to make a splash like twitter, uber which show splash on the cold start. [react-native-splash-screen package](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen) giving me ability to show splash on cold start but because of the abouve mentioned issue I cannot use it. Can anyone please guide me how to resolve this issue and achieve this type of splash screen.

Comment: https://medium.com/handlebar-labs/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-to-a-react-native-app-ios-and-android-30a3cec835ae

Comment: https://medium.com/@yosua1011/how-to-add-splash-screen-to-react-native-app-under-10-minutes-android-react-native-0-50-e19ed01b632b

Comment: @NileshRathod I have already mentioned this article of your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this workaround.

You can add the splash screen inside your JS code. Use AppState to identify if your app is on a cold start or state change from background to foreground.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html

Comment: could you please explain? for cold start only.

Comment: Use componentWillMount hook of your App's start component(first component of your app) to show your splash screen with a timeout and then render your view. This componentWillMount hook will only trigger on a cold start. If the app is inactive or in background mode there will be no any mounting of this first component.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're here for this is probably that you couldn't find the correct, updated, and easiest solution to this till now!

Please follow these steps to add splash screen:

https://dev.to/cmcodes/how-to-add-splash-screen-in-a-react-native-android-app-287l

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30392516)